# Why is my concrete soft and crumbly after more than 14 hours?

Tags: concrete, mold, cement

So I'm trying to create a concrete pencil holder but the last few times I've tried, the cement has not dried and comes out really crumbly and is soft and damp and dusty, even after curing all night. I'm using FastCrete cement which says it goes hard after 15 minutes. I'm a beginner in the whole concrete thing so I'm not sure what to do. Any advice?

Comment: Are you adding any sand? Straight cement has no real strength adding sand will give it some strength.

Comment: No I'm not, I didn't think I would need it but I'll give it a try. Do you think that will solve the problem of it still coming out damp though, even after so long?

Comment: If you don't think you need it you will continue to have the same results. Google mortar mix (that is what you are making) you will find sand is required.

Comment: I'm using cement, not mortar, will that make a difference?

Comment: concrete is not cement.

Comment: Ok you've really confused me now, if you can't tell, I'm very new to this. Would you please explain

Comment: FastCrete is a just add water product, no sand needed.  Try less water, I'm guessing your adding too much.  When mixed it should be thick mud.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that, if I were to add to much, would it have the same result of I just leave it longer?

Comment: No. Too much water won't just eventually dry out.  The water is the catalyst for a chemical reaction.

Comment: The fastcrete product page says 2.5-3.5 L water per 20 kg bag so make sure you stick to that ratio. Try weighing the amount that goes into your pencil holder mold and do the math from there to find a reasonable range for water to add. Also as per instructions make sure you pour the mix in slowly, so that it all gets wet as it's filling. It also says to sprinkle a *small* amount of water on top if the top surface didnt get wet while pouring.

Comment: @Ed Fastcrete: http://www.cemix.co.nz/products/bagged-concrete-mortar-products/fastcrete no sand or mixing needed. Water only, 15 minute theoretical set time.

Comment: If the concrete or cement or whatever you want to call it dries out to fast, it will be no stronger than what the OP has described.

Comment: Sounds like my original statement cement needs sand and water to make mortar, cement needs aggregate all in the proper amounts,,, I encourage you to keep doing the same if you want the same results!!!!!!!!!